# How to delete wallet without deleting blockchain

Tags: wallet, watch-only

I am registering some addresses as watch only addresses and I would like the ability to reset my wallet without having to sync again. Can I just delete my wallet.dat?

I use Bitcoin Core version 16.1.

This wallet does not handle any private keys with a non-zero balance.

**Warning: Deleting `wallet.dat` will make you lose your Bitcoins if your wallet has a non-zero balance!**

Comment: Yes, you can just delete the wallet.dat

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Raghav already commented:

Yes, you can delete the `wallet.dat` file as long as you don't have any private keys in it. Once you restart Bitcoin Core it creates a new and `wallet.dat`.

Comment: as long as you don't have any private keys in it *with a non-zero balance which you don't have tested backups of*